# To select particular row and column in DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My requirement is little bit complex
**below give is a DataFrame df:**

```
                       Month1 Month2   Month3   Month4 Month5  Month6
Credit               4644.5  11142  6198.33  2830.48   5886  8381.5
No. of transactions       8      4        6       14      6       4
```

so what I want is, I want to save all of these values in a separate variables. 
**For example, end result should be:**

```
CreditMonth1 = 4644.5
CreditMonth2 = 11142 
...
so on.. and
No. of transactionsMonth1 = 8
No. of transactionsMonth2 = 4
...
so on..
```

the above result can be achieved using the following code:

```
CreditMonth1= df.at['Credit', 'Month1']
```

but the challenge that I'm facing over here is that the columns are not always constant. Sometimes it will have value for all 6 months some time it wont.

**for example:**

```
                       Month1   Month2   Month3 
Credit                 5566.45  14275    6194.88  
No. of transactions       4      5        3
```

**Expected result**

I want to get individual data for all months(till 6 months). if in case of the above example of 3 months data, I want to fill in the rest of the months value (ie. `Month 4` to `Month 6` to be `'0'`

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Did you try to use a dictionnary instead of variables  : pandas.DataFrame.to_dict ?

Comment: actually in the end I wand to save all of these individual data in CSV so `DataFrame.to_dict` didn't gave me a satisfactory answer

Comment: What about looping through the dict keys ?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: for key, value in my_dict.items():

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually worked and solved my problem

```
try:
    if df.at['Credit', 'Month4']:
    SalaryMonth4 = df.at['Salary', 'Month4']
except:
    SalaryMonth4 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

use `to_dict`. See if this works for you

df

```
                   Month1  Month2   Month3   Month4  Month5  Month6
Name                                                               
Credit             4644.5   11142  6198.33  2830.48    5886  8381.5
No.oftransactions     8.0       4     6.00    14.00       6     4.0


['No.Of Transaction{} : {}'.format(key,value) for key, value in df.to_dict(orient='index')['No.oftransactions'].items()]

['{} : {}'.format(key,value) for key, value in df.to_dict(orient='index')['Credit'].items()]
```

Output

```
['No.Of TransactionMonth1 : 8.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth2 : 4.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth3 : 6.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth4 : 14.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth5 : 6.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth6 : 4.0']

['Month1 : 4644.5',
 'Month2 : 11142.0',
 'Month3 : 6198.33',
 'Month4 : 2830.48',
 'Month5 : 5886.0',
 'Month6 : 8381.5']
```

**Update**

df

```
                   Month2   Month3   Month4  Month5  Month6
Name                                                       
Credit              11142  6198.33  2830.48    5886  8381.5
No.oftransactions       4     6.00    14.00       6     4.0

credit = df.to_dict(orient='index')['Credit']
transaction = df.to_dict(orient='index')['No.oftransactions']

['{} : {}'.format('Month{}'.format(key),credit.get('Month{}'.format(key))) for key in range(1,6) ]
```

Output

```
Out[455]:

    ['Month1 : None',
     'Month2 : 11142.0',
     'Month3 : 6198.33',
     'Month4 : 2830.48',
     'Month5 : 5886.0']


['No.Of Transaction{} : {}'.format('Month{}'.format(key),transaction.get('Month{}'.format(key))) for key in range(1,6)]
```

Output

```
['No.Of TransactionMonth1 : None',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth2 : 4.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth3 : 6.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth4 : 14.0',
 'No.Of TransactionMonth5 : 6.0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select specific row with [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) function like `df.iloc[some_index]`. After that, you can iterate through rows by hand. Other option would be to use `df.iterrows()` in a loop. That way again, you get each separate row and if you do `for index, row in df.iterrows()` then all the data is in the `row` variable.

**Update**

```
for index, data in df.iterrows():
  for m in ['Month_1', .. , 'Month_6']:
    if data[m] == '':
      data[m].replace('', 0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: what about the 3 months case I have mentioned in the question. I want rest of the values to be filled with `0` if that particular months are not present

Comment: Well you can see what's in the row and fill the other values by hand in a loop. If `row['Month_4']` returns `error` or `null` or whatever just put `0` in it's place